# facebook comments widget - how to monitor latest comments?

Tags: facebook, widget, comments

I have over 10,000 pages on my website. I just created a php script to automatically integrate the facebook comments widget into each pages.

However, i was wondering if there is a way to monitor the latest comments added to my website so i don't have to browse through 10,000 pages to see the latest comments.

I am also wondering if i will be able to delete comments by other users ? How can facebook tell that i am the webmaster of the page ? If some user leave nasty comments on one of the pages i want to be able to delete them

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) allows you to query for Facebook data, including comments. It's pretty easy to use but does require a bit of code to make web requests, parse JSON, etc. You can pass in filters, such as only wanting comments after a certain date, which makes querying for "new comments" simple.

The API will return all comments (even those deleted by you; afaik there is no way to tell whether a particular comment has been deleted). The results are returned in pages, so importing a lot of comments can take a bit (as you need multiple round-trips). Also, there is no way to use the API to delete posts - this has to go through the Facebook web pages (or some other means I don't know about).

The documentation pages are pretty exhaustive and will explain how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you want to add face book comment box in your website . then just go to face book **plugin's** and copy the comment box **(CODE)** .

now open your website admin penal . if your website created in blogger then go to layout . if in other setup. then go to plugin's . you see some layout hear add your code in (top down ) bar .

if you doesn't understand then 2nd way.
go to website and open your dashboard now go to website template . now edit the template .
now you see some codes in new tab . scroll down and put your cods in HTML Body place .

i think you understand : for more shahzebraza425@yahoo .com / www.megaphotocompetition .com /
www.shahzebraza .tk / www.wuwsoftware .tk